# Quarkus RESTEasy default dependency, workaround for getting the uploaded file name without custom html parsing

Tags: amazon-s3, microservices, resteasy, quarkus

I am trying to develop one microservice which will upload file to the Amazon S3 cloud. As Quarkus uses RESTEasy as default so I am unable to use MultipartFile provided by the org.springboot.web.multipart.MultipartFile.  Then I have decided to use RESTEasy but after going through this link [@MultipartForm How to get the original file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333298/multipartform-how-to-get-the-original-file-name) no hope left.  Is there really no option to get the name and extension of the uploaded file without parsing an HTML file? If not how can I exclude the RESTEasy dependency, so that MultipartFile of the spring-boot can work? Without original file name and extension uploading files in Amazon S3 makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that's something we should improve in RESTEasy and Quarkus.

Right now, to my knowledge, there's nothing better than the SO answer you pointed out. JAX-RS doesn't provide anything for that so we would need some specific RESTEasy extension to simplify all that.

Could you open a Quarkus issue to initiate the discussion? https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues

I will ping the appropriate people there to try to get this ball running.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have opened an issue but no one really noticed. [link](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7942)