# How to get originalName from a File in quarkus

Tags: file-upload, upload, quarkus

I have an api in quarkus java when I upload the file I can't get the original name of it. When I use File.getName the return I get is this pfx16311440985252189274sfx

```
 `
package br.com.upload.controller;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.multipart.MultipartForm;

import br.com.upload.entity.MultipartBody;

@Path("upload")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UploadController {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public String sendUploada(@MultipartForm MultipartBody data) throws IOException {

        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(data.file));

        // String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);

        // Long size = data.file.length();

        System.out.println("data file " + data.file.getName());

        Files.copy(is,
                new File("/home/allanfenx/Público/Java/upload/src/main/resources/upload",
                        "mai.png")
                                .toPath(),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        return data.fileName;
    }
}`


`package br.com.upload.entity;

import java.io.File;

import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.multipart.PartType;

public class MultipartBody {

    @FormParam("file")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public File file;

    @FormParam("fileName")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String fileName;

}`
```

This is my code quarkus uses InputStream but I'm using File. The code works perfectly but I can't get the original file name. The return I have is pfx16311440985252189274sfx it looks like they are characters to be decoded

Answer (score 1):

I've been through this a few days ago.

Unfortunately using Resteasy annotation, there is no way to get the filename directly. You have to parse the filename from request header 'Content-disposition', something like you can find here : [@MultipartForm How to get the original file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333298/multipartform-how-to-get-the-original-file-name)

However something's not mentionned: you can use 'quarkus-resteasy-reactive' implementation as explained here : https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive
You'll find a nice `FileUpload` class that can give you what you want.
WARNING though: changing JAX-RS implementation to reactive might impact your entire app so I advise you to read quarkus documentation if you do that :)

Comment: If I use quarkus-resteasy-reactive will my entire application be reactive?
no more thanks

Comment: Only your JAX-RS related processes (managing RESTful Web Services for instance). If you want a full reactive app you should use reactive implementations of all your tools (ex: hibernate-reactive).

Whatever your decision, maybe Multipart management shouldn't be driving it :)